# The problem of python list remove function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know it is maybe a duplicate question. But due to my poor English expression,I don't know how to search it.

Recently I find a problem in python list.remove,Here is the code:

```
data = []
for i in range(1000):
    Tempdict = {}
    Tempdict["code"] = str(i)
    data.append(Tempdict)

codes_to_keep = ("1","8","80")
for i in data:
    if not i["code"] in codes_to_keep:
        data.remove(i)

print(data) #{"code":"1","code":"3","code":"5".......},it will keep odd number leave.
```

Or if I use this to delete number which need to be de:

```
data = []
for i in range(1000):
    Tempdict = {}
    Tempdict["code"] = str(i)
    data.append(Tempdict)

codes_to_delete = ("1","8","80")
for i in data:
    if i["code"] in codes_to_delete:
        data.remove(i)

print(data) #{"code":"0","code":"2"xxx},This is what I expected
```

What happened?

Comment: I know there is a way to achieve this is to use ``result = list(item for item in data if item["code"] in codes_to_keep)``

Comment: you're editing list during iterating over it. Thats not recommended.

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/

Comment: don"t use `if not a in b` but `if a not in b`

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/not-python

Answer (score 0):

For the proper answer,

```
data = []
for i in range(1000):
    Tempdict = {}
    Tempdict["code"] = str(i)
    data.append(Tempdict)


codes_to_keep = ("1","8","80")
# for i in data:
#     if not i["code"] in codes_to_keep:
#         data.remove(i)

data = list(item for item in data if item["code"] in codes_to_keep)

print(data)
```

```
[{'code': '1'}, {'code': '8'}, {'code': '80'}]
```

Comment: Sure,I know this idea.I have written it in my question comment.But still thanks~